# Wall decals above crib?

Tags: infant, newborn, crib

There's a warning for "do not hang wall decals above the babies crib" on the set of wall decals we got from the store.

That was really our ***main*** plan for where to put them, as the wall above the crib was going to be so bare due to not wanting anything heavy above the crib... for obvious reasons.

Does anyone know why this warning would be present?  Is it a CYA on the manufacturers part?  Or is there a legitimate reason I'm not thinking of?

Comment: I don't know so won't make it an answer, but I can imagine there's some failure rate where the decals fall off the wall, and potentially into the crib to be eaten or other bad things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Eric's comment above - the concern is probably that they will fall off the ceiling or wall off and get into the crib.

There's also a chance, if the decal is meant to be semi-permanent, that a child could scratch at the decal and peel it off the wall if its in reach.

If you sealed the decal to the wall (glue, or a clear coat over top) you should be pretty safe. However this will make it difficult to remove the decal later. You may need to run a sander over it to get it off.